# how to set value using php inside <a></a> tag

Tags: php, html

Basically, I'm trying to set the title against the value which came from DB but when I make a PHP statement in inverted commas to set title the tag got disturbed. Any Suggestions ??

```
<?php 
$Institute_Code=$_GET['Institute_Code'];
echo ?> 
<td><a id="bookmark-this" value= "hi" href="#" title="<?php $Institute_Code ?>" >Bookmark This Page</a><td>
```

Comment: "inverted commas"?  "tag got disturbed"?  It's not clear at all what you're describing.

Comment: You need to echo $Institute_Code.

Comment: @David tag got disturbed means it gives error of unexpected "?>"

Comment: @NaveedCheema: That would be because of your unfinished `echo` statement on the third line.  If you're not echoing anything, remove the statement.

Comment: @DaveChen problem remain the same "syntax error, unexpected '?>' "

Comment: And a semicolon at the end of a statement. I'd recommend [reading this](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't printing the $Institute_Code variable

You have...

```
 title="<?php $Institute_Code ?>"
```

You need to use one of these methods

```
     title="<?php echo $Institute_Code; ?>"
```

OR

```
     title="<?=$Institute_Code?>"
```

Also, the other `echo ?>` will cause an error, make that just `?>`

Comment: Thank You very much I got it (: @duane

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some big knowledge gaps in PHP. I recommend you to read some basic tutorials first in order to understand your code.
The answer to your concrete question would be: Syntax!

```
<?php $Institute_Code=$_GET['Institute_Code']; ?> 
<td><a id="bookmark-this" value="hi" href="#" title="<?= $Institute_Code ?>" >Bookmark This Page</a><td>
```

You need to echo your variable. Either do `<?php echo $Institute_Code; ?>` or do `<?= $Institute_Code ?>` what is the equivalent shortcode to it.

Comment: Thanks (: and yes I'm new to PHP. . . . Sorry for inconvenience